# Namespace for wsse:security

Tags: spring, xml-namespaces, spring-ws, wss4j, wsse

My problem is i am trying to call a web service which has Wss4jSecurityInterceptor for username password authentication.

the request which is generated is like this :

```xml
<wsse:Security
            xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
            xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
            SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1">
```

this is not working but when i change the namespace i.e. **xmlns:wsse**

```xml
<wsse:Security
            xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/secext"
            SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1">
```

it works fine.

i want to know how i can change the namespace that is generated with the `<wsse:Security>` tag from my code

Answer (score 0):

You could extends [EndpointInterceptorAdapter](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/2.0/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/server/endpoint/interceptor/EndpointInterceptorAdapter.html) and override the method handleResponse like this:

```
@Override
public boolean handleResponse(MessageContext messageContext_, Object endpoint_) {

WebServiceMessage _webServiceMessage = messageContext_.getResponse();
SoapMessage _soapMessage = (SoapMessage) _webServiceMessage;


if (_soapMessage != null) {
SoapEnvelope _soapEnvelope = _soapMessage.getEnvelope();

if (_soapEnvelope != null) {

SoapHeader _soapHeader =_soapEnvelope.getHeader();
// modify the soapheader by casting to a DOMSource and manipulate the nodes
```